# How to extract key value pairs from a list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, extract

I have a string like
`header=[KeyVal(key='abc',value='123'),KeyVal(key='xyz',value='456')]`

Need to end up with a dictionary like this:
`{'abc':'123','xyz':'456'}`

Tried creating dictionary but not getting far. What is the pythonic way to achieve this?
G

Comment: If `KeyVal` is a `NamedTuple` (or any other class that is an iterable of exactly two elements) then `dict(header)` will work.

Comment: Is `header=[KeyVal...` really a **string** or is that a line in your code ?

Answer (score -1):

```
header=[KeyVal(key='abc',value='123'),KeyVal(key='xyz',value='456')]
result = {kv.key: kv.value for kv in header}
```